# Search a value in a range and compare it to another range. If it exists, give it a specific value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two ranges (both 2 dimensional). R1(H1:M4) contains the list of a few possible values of the cells in R2(A6:N15). R2 may contain blank cells. If a cell in R2 matches a cell in R1, I want to output the last cell in the column (N1:N4) in the matched value of R1.

I am using the following formula in P6 (nested Iferror):

```
IF(A6="", "Blank", 
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $H$1:$N$4, 7,FALSE), 
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $I$1:$N$4, 6,FALSE), 
      IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $J$1:$N$4, 5,FALSE), 
        IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $K$1:$N$4, 4,FALSE), 
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $L$1:$N$4, 3,FALSE), 
            IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $M$1:$N$4, 2,FALSE), 
              IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6, $N$1:$N$4, 1,FALSE), "None"))))))))
```

Note that I am using the range H1:N4 because of Vlookup.

This is giving me a solution, but I want a more efficient solution.

Comment: [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) ?

Comment: That probably doesn't give you the solution you think it does. Each of those VLOOKUPs will only look in column H1:H4 for G45. You are only **ever** going to return the value from column N, never from H:M.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim R1 As Variant, R2 As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Set R1 = Range("H1:M4")
    Set R2 = Range("A6:N15")
    For Each x In R1
        If x.Value = "" Then
        GoTo skip
         End If

        For Each y In R2
            If y.Value = "" Then
                y.Offset(0, 16) = "Blank"
            ElseIf x = y Then
            y.Offset(0, 16) = x
            End If
        Next y
skip:
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd rather not use a Goto statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
Sub FindMatches()
    Dim R1 As Variant, R2 As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Set R1 = Range("H1:M4")
    Set R2 = Range("A6:N15")
    For Each x In R1
        If x.Value = "" Then
        End If
        For Each y In R2
            If y.Value = "" Then
                y.Offset(0, 16) = "Blank"
            ElseIf x.value = y.value Then
                y.Offset(0, 16) = x.Offset(0, 7 - x.Column)
            End If
        Next y
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindThem()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell As Range
Dim strng As String
Dim i As Long, iRow As Long, nCol As Long

Set rng1 = Range("H1:M4")
Set rng2 = Range("A6:N15")
nCol = rng1.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
    strng = strng & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng1.Rows(i))), "-") & "-"
Next i
strng = "-" & strng ' this is the string that collects all rng1 values

For Each cell In rng2
    i = InStr(strng, "-" & cell.Value & "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        iRow = Len(Left(strng, i + 1)) - Len(Replace(Left(strng, i + 1), "-", "")) ' count the "position" of the value in the string
        cell.Offset(, 16) = rng1(Int(iRow / nCol) + IIf(iRow Mod nCol = 0, 0, 1), 7)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

which makes much less iterations than looping through both R1 and R2

it would be fine to know which is the fastest, provided speed is an issue you're facing

of course, but that should be an issue for all possible solutions, values in R1 must be unique, otherwise only their first occurrence in R2 (searching row by row and then column by column) would be catched